# replaceChild not inserting new child

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I do not see what I am doing wrong:

```
        var html = existingSelector.innerHTML;
        var node = document.createTextNode(html);
        existingSelector.parentNode.replaceChild(node, existingSelector);
```

`existingSelector` is the result of

```
selectedContents.querySelector("b");
```

Running the code correctly removes the "b" element, but does not insert the new node in its place. It simply deletes the entire node, without actually replacing it. As far as I can see, my syntax for the replaceChild() is correct though - ideas?

Edited Complete code:

```
    this.bold = function() {
    var selection = this.selection;
    var selectedContents = selection.extractContents();

    var existingSelector = selectedContents.querySelector("b");

    if (existingSelector) {
        var html = existingSelector.innerHTML;
        var node = document.createTextNode(html);
        console.log(node);
        existingSelector.parentNode.replaceChild(node, existingSelector);
    }
    else {
        var b = document.createElement("b");
        b.appendChild(selectedContents);
        selection.deleteContents();
        selection.insertNode(b);            
    }

    this.restoreSelection(selection);
}
```

Comment: What does `console.log(node)` show?  Can you reproduce the problem on http://jsfiddle.net?

Comment: From here it looks like you're essentially replacing *existingSelector* with itself. What am I missing?

Comment: This is part of a rich text editor I'm building based on contenteditable. I've updated original post with more context of the entire function, this.selection is a saved range of selection from the text editor. replaceChild() deletes the b element but does not replace it with just the plain text as intended

Comment: console.log(node) shows the html as expected. It all seems to work fine right up to the call to replaceChild(), when the node is deleted but not replaced. The node to be deleted is the child of a contenteditable div.

Comment: I cannot reproduce the problem -- https://jsfiddle.net/f99s91x2/. What if you comment out `this.restoreSelection(selection)`?

Comment: No effect on solving the problem. I can't reproduce it either, the fiddles that are being linked are all working flawlessly. Something's wrong. I've found an alternative solution that by deleting the selection's contents and inserting the new node, which works. I'll look further into this later

Comment: Is the rich text editor contained in a frame or in the same document that contains the JS script?

Comment: It is in the same document. I still haven't figured this out, using an alternative solution for now.